# trouble copying data from one table to another with auto increment field

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL statement which was working perfectly until I moved it to another server. The middle query (encapsulated in ** ) does not seem to work. I am getting an error saying that 'AUTO' is an incorrect integer type. If I remove it altogether, it says that I have an incorrect number of fields. I am trying to copy data from one table to another and allow the destination table to auto increment its ID number.

```
          SET sql_safe_updates=0;
          START TRANSACTION;
          DELETE FROM shares
          WHERE asset_id = '$asset_ID';

          /*************************************************************/
          INSERT INTO shares
          SELECT 'AUTO', asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner, is_approved
          FROM pending_share_changes
          WHERE asset_ID = '$asset_ID';
          /*************************************************************/

          DELETE FROM pending_share_changes
          WHERE asset_ID = '$asset_ID';
          DELETE FROM shares
          WHERE asset_ID = '$asset_ID' AND percent_owner = '0';
          COMMIT;";
```

Comment: yes, there is. basically, table 1 has current data. table 2 gets newly proposed data. if approved, this query deletes the data from table 1, copies table 2 data over to table 1, then deletes the data from table 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) page of the mysql docs, you have to do:

```
INSERT INTO shares 
  (column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, column_name4) -- changed!
SELECT asset_ID, member_ID, percent_owner, is_approved
FROM pending_share_changes
WHERE asset_ID = '$asset_ID';
```

The difference is that the column names of the "receiving" table are explicitly listed after the name of the receiving table.

The docs say

> AUTO_INCREMENT columns work as usual.

Comment: That seemed to work! Just not sure why it works on my Win7 box and not my Win2k8. Either way, the new code runs fine on both. Thanks!